# Criterion for triviality of a line bundle on a projective scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-schemes

Let $X$ be a projective scheme over $\mathbb{C}$ with a very ample line bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$. Let $L$ be a line bundle on $X$ and suppose that $\dim_{\mathbb{C}} H^i(L(d)) = \dim_{\mathbb{C}} H^i(\mathcal{O}_X(d))$ for all integers $i \geq 0$ and $d \in \mathbb{Z}$. Does this imply that $L \cong \mathcal{O}_X$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes (for integral $X$). Moreover, it is enough to have this equality for $i = 0$ only.

First, when $d = 0$ and $i = 0$ we have $H^0(O_X) = k$, hence $H^0(L) = k$. It gives an exact sequence
$$
0 \to  O_X \to  L \to F \to 0,
$$
where $F$ is a coherent sheaf on $X$. Now twist the sequence by $O_X(d)$ with $d \gg 0$. Then $H^1(O_X(d)) = 0$, hence exact sequence of cohomology gives
$$
0 \to H^0(O_X(d)) \to H^0(L(d)) \to H^0(F(d)) \to 0.
$$
The first two terms have the same dimension, hence $H^0(F(d)) = 0$. Since this is true for all $d \gg 0$, it follows that $F = 0$, hence $L \cong O_X$.

EDIT. In the nonintegral case this is wrong. As an example, let $X$ be a reducible conic (a union of two lines intersecting at a point). Let $L$ be the line bundle that restricts as $O(1)$ to one of the lines and as $O(-1)$ to the other. Then an easy verification shows that $H^i(O_X(d)) = H^i(L(d))$ for all $i$ and $d$, still $L$ is not isomorphic to $O_X$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm specifically interested in the non-integral case.

Comment: What an elegant illustration of Serre's results on coherent sheaves over projective varieties! +1, and I encourage users also to upvote this brilliant answer.

Comment: Dear Bubbles, the integral case is certainly the most natural and interesting one. What is the specific situation you have in mind that cannot be reduced to the integral case?

Comment: @Bubbles: I added a counterexample in non-integral case.